# django s3 boto file upload TypeError: invalid file: <InMemoryUploadedFile:

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload a file from postman to s3 and getting error on
k.set_contents_from_filename(file)
TypeError: invalid file:  
Can you please take look? Thanks a lot.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField(required=True, max_length=None, use_url=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=500)
```

views.py

```
import logging
from boto.s3.key import Key

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import ResourceSerializer
from .utils import create_boto_connection
from django.conf import settings


class Resource(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ResourceSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            context = {}
            file = serializer.validated_data['file']
            name = serializer.validated_data['name']
            ext = file.name.split('.')[-1]
            new_file_name = '{file}.{ext}'.format(file=name, ext=ext)
            file_name_with_dir = 'profile_photos/{}'.format(new_file_name)
            # Create s3boto connection
            conn = create_boto_connection()
            try:
                bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
                k = Key(bucket)
                k.key = file_name_with_dir
                k.set_contents_from_filename(file)
                k.make_public()
                context['file'] = new_file_name
            except Exception as e:
                context['message'] = 'Failed to process request'
                # Logging Exceptions
                logging.exception(e)
                logging.debug("Could not upload to S3")
            return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

utils.py

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

from django.conf import settings


def create_boto_connection():
    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    # conn = boto.connect_s3()
    return conn
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from s3boto import views

urlpatterns = [
    # v1
    url(r'^v1/s3boto/upload-resource/$', views.Resource.as_view(), name="upload-resource"),
]
```

postman: [image]

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: ERROR:root:invalid file: <InMemoryUploadedFile: 123444444.jpeg (image/jpeg)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ranvijay/work/opt/Everest-platform/s3boto/views.py", line 30, in post
    k.set_contents_from_filename(file)
  File "/Users/ranvijay/work/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1358, in set_contents_from_filename
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
TypeError: invalid file: <InMemoryUploadedFile: 123444444.jpeg (image/jpeg)>
[02/Feb/2016 10:55:31] "POST /api/v1/s3boto/upload-resource/ HTTP/1.1" 201 39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a django `InMemoryUploadedFile` to the method  `set_content_from_filename`, which expects a string.

From the [boto documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_filename):

> **set_contents_from_filename**(filename, headers=None, replace=True, cb=None, num_cb=10, policy=None, md5=None, reduced_redundancy=False, encrypt_key=False)
>
> *Store an object in S3 using the name of the Key object as the key in
>   S3 and the contents of the file named by ‘filename’. See
>   set_contents_from_file method for details about the parameters.*

Either use [`set_content_from_file`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_file) or save the file to a local temporary file and pass that filename to `set_content_from_filename`.

Comment: Thanks u very much Håken Lid :)